# How to disable trackpad for HP Elitebook 840 G5

Tags: windows-10, laptop, touchpad

As the question states, I am simply trying to disable my touchpad on my HP laptop.  So I think this is very specific for the HP Elitebook 840 G5 as I have tried the following generic methods to disable the trackpad:

1. Under mouse settings, using the Synaptics tab. This tab does not exist for me. (Reference https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03882926)
2. Disabling the Synaptics driver. I thought this would work for sure too but I tried to disable all of the mouse drivers available under Mice and other pointing devices (Device Manager) and the trackpad still works.
3. Using third party software. I tried "touchpad-blocker" and even when enabled, the touchpad still works.
4. Double tapping the top left corner (https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/how-do-i-disable-a-touchpad-on-an-hp-elitebook-850-laptop/td-p/5480918) This does nothing for mine.

I am open for other suggestions. I am really surprised that disabling the driver didn't work.

Comment: Hi. I have a huge favor to ask. I have the same laptop for work and I am trying to get some information from it. I can't install anything on it so I have no way to get the information I need. Would you be willing to use a registry compare program to see what setting gets changed when you enable/disable touchpad? You can see details of what I'm after at https://www.reddit.com/r/Hewlett_Packard/comments/bu7uxi/i_have_a_favor_to_ask_of_anyone_that_has_an_hp/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PC Settings --> Touchpad --> Leave touchpad on when a mouse is connected.
Uncheck the setting the disable the touchpad when a mouse is connected.

[image]

Comment: ha.. That is actually correct. I feel so silly now as I never knew or saw the "touchpad" under settings. Thanks so much!

Comment: I just got a 840 G5 and was searching for it as well.

Answer (score -1):

According to the drivers page it appears the Synaptics in your PC is for the fingerprint sensor. Either the touchpad isn't Synaptics-brand and/or the driver didn't install correctly. Try to install this driver then look in Mouse Settings or look for HP touchpad app in Start menu or Control Panel (under HW usually, otherwise change view to Large Icons)
https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-elitebook-840-g5-notebook-pc/18491271/swItemId/ob-216153-1

Alternatively you could check BIOS (usually F9 or F10) to see if you can disable it there. Sometimes there is also a Fn key dedicated to it. Here is another HP article on disabling their 'clickpad'. Don't ask me how they are different lol
https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04648748#AbT2

Comment: The touchpad is Synaptics. The driver is installed as "Synaptics HID ClickPad"

Comment: I put 'and/or the driver didn't install correctly' & I still believe that. You can install just the barebone drivers for HW, but the full driver install really should give you that Synaptics tab or some other HP program (2nd link) since wanting to disable it is usually available. So I'd re-install the driver I linked to & report back

Comment: I installed the one you sent a link to but still can't disable the pad

Comment: Are you still not getting the Synaptics tab? I'd call HP if you still have a warranty, maybe they've seen this. I'm at a loss short of the links I provided. Maybe you can look for the synaptics executable that I'm guessing that control panel tab's button runs?